# Creating a tweet button without opening a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, twitter

I'm looking to add a "tweet this" button to a site. Simple enough, right? The catch is that the site is meant to run on an embedded platform that doesn't particularly handle popup windows, so I'm trying to do everything inside the page.

I'm able to successfully create my tweet button, attach an onClick handler to it, and construct a proper twitter.com/share URL for the relevant content. All works fine when I open that URL in a new window with window.open. However, if I try to open the URL in an iframe, nothing loads inside the frame. Even loading http://twitter.com into the iframe fails in the same way. However, loading Google or any other website seems to work just fine.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing here? Thanks! --zach

**Edit:**
Yep, they are detecting the iframe on load and blanking the page:

```
if (window.top !== window.self) {
    document.write = "";
    window.top.location = window.self.location; 
    setTimeout(function(){ document.body.innerHTML='';},1);
    window.self.onload=function(evt){document.body.innerHTML='';};
```

}

Any reasonable way to get around this, or am I stuck writing my own auth pipeline through oauth? I don't need anything from their API, just letting users tweet to their own accounts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Twitter (like Stack Overflow) is probably using some Javascript to ensure they're not being presented in an iFrame:

```
if(top!=self){
     //hates you
}
```

I ran into something similar recently, and ended up re-doing part of my app without the iFrame element.

Answer (score 2):

Go and get a developper account on twitter and things are made easy for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you simply redirect the the twitter share URL? I'm guessing they want to be careful about opening the window in iframe's to prevent malicious sites from tweeting in a user's account without giving the user a chance to first confirm their intent to send this tweet.

Answer (score 0):

You said window.open worked fine for popping up the url in a new window but have you tried popping it into the parent frame?

```
twtWindow=window.open([url],'_parent',[specs])
```

Answer (score 0):

@yuval Unfortunately for you, the twitter url goes to a page that has the X-FRAME-OPTIONS:SAMEORIGIN header set in the response. It's not a Javascript check. The browser will simply refuse to render the page after seeing the header. This is done to prevent a [clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking) attack, usually done to steal a user's password.

So your only other option is really to redirect your current page with `window.location.href=url`.